# How to use tabindex and arrow key over group of radio and input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form similar to as shown below. There are group of radios and input field corresponding to it.

[image: form page]

Condition it should follow

1. first tab index select first radio of group 1. Incase selection has to be changed i can use arrow key
2. second tab index should select first radio from group 2. Incase selection has to be changed i can use arrow key
3. while in group 2 if i press tab again it should focus on textbox corresponding to radio
4. pressing tab again should take focus to group 3 textbox

All of above condition are working except when first radio of group 2 is selected. pressing tab does take it to corresponding textbox. But on again pressing tab it goes to another textbox of group 2 (which should not happen).

Please help. HTML code as below

```html
<html>
     <body>
      Please select gender (Group 1)<br>
       <input type="radio" checked name="gender" tabindex="1" value="male"> Male<br>
       <input type="radio" name="gender"tabindex="1" value="female"> Female
    <br><br>


      Please select one of following (Group 2)<br>
       <input type="radio" checked name="payment"tabindex="2" value="amount"> $<input type="text" tabindex="2.1"><br>
       <input type="radio" name="payment" tabindex="2" value="installment">#<input type="text" tabindex="2.1">
      <br><br>


       Please select payment date (Group 3)<br>
       <input type="text" tabindex="3">

     </body>
    </html>
```

<< Try pressing tab key when cursor is at postion as shown in the image >>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your post is tagged with javascript, I assume javascript is allowed. Disabling the input-field will prevent 'tabbing' to it. So disable the text-field after the '#' by default (by adding `disabled="disabled"`) and add onchange-events to the radio-buttons to disable the text-field after '$' and enable the text-field after '#' (and vice versa).

```
onchange="document.getElementById('amount').disabled=null; document.getElementById('installment').disabled='disabled'; "
```

And add the proper `id`'s to the text-field, so the javascript-selectors will work.

Full code:

```html
<html>
     <body>
      Please select gender (Group 1)<br>
       <input type="radio" checked name="gender" tabindex="1" value="male"> Male<br>
       <input type="radio" name="gender"tabindex="1" value="female"> Female
    <br><br>


      Please select one of following (Group 2)<br>
       <input type="radio" checked name="payment"tabindex="2" value="amount" onchange="document.getElementById('amount').disabled=null; document.getElementById('installment').disabled='disabled'; "> $<input type="text" tabindex="2.1" id="amount"><br>
       <input type="radio" name="payment" tabindex="2" value="installment" onchange="document.getElementById('amount').disabled='disabled'; document.getElementById('installment').disabled=null; ">#<input type="text" tabindex="2.1" disabled="disabled" id="installment">
      <br><br>


       Please select payment date (Group 3)<br>
       <input type="text" tabindex="3">

     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The benefit of this solution is that users can't access the textbox with a click device either, e.g. they are not able to fill out a textbox which is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could set `tabindex="-1"` with JavaScript on the not selected textbox, therefore this textbox will be ignored in the tab order by the browser. Then you can get rid of all those manual tabindex definitions as well, because the browser will already follow the desired tab order by default.